# Request.Post Method to Web Server using CherryPy

Tags: request, webserver, cherrypy

I am following the blog: [Build your own Python RESTful Web Service](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-python-restful-web-service-840ed7766832) to mock a web server using **cherrypy**.

The server code is

```
import cherrypy

class MyWebService(object):
   @cherrypy.expose
   @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
   @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
   def process(self):
      return "hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'}
    cherrypy.config.update(config)
    cherrypy.quickstart(MyWebService())
```

running above script by `python server.py` will start a service at `http://localhost:8080`.

**Successful Call**

Then we can call the service using post method:

```
import requests
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/process', headers=headers, json={})
```

It successfully returns "hello world!" with status= 200.

**Failed Call**

However, if changing "Content-Type": **application/json** -> **text/plain** in headers and **json** -> **data**:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/process', headers=headers, data={})
```

It responds the error code **415**, and the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hshung/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hshung/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/hshung/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/hshung/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

.....
```

I did try the following server code

```
@cherrypy.tools.json_in(content_type=['application/json', 'text/plain'])
```

The API call still fails, and the status code is **400**.

Can anyone who is familiar with cherryPy and API request help me figure out how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/process', headers=headers, data={})
```

You're sending a `POST` request with an empty body, it should work if you specify the `data` param as a string containing any valid json:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/process', headers=headers, data='{}')
```

For reference take a look a the values that are sent:

```
>>> requests.post('http://localhost:8080/process', headers=headers, json={})
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:8080
send: b'POST /process HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\n\r\n'
send: b'{}'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Server: CherryPy/18.6.1
header: Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2022 23:16:49 GMT
header: Content-Length: 14
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:8080 "POST /process HTTP/1.1" 200 14
<Response [200]>

>>> requests.post('http://localhost:8080/process', headers=headers, data={})
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:8080
send: b'POST /process HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
header: Server: CherryPy/18.6.1
header: Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2022 23:16:55 GMT
header: Content-Length: 3023
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:8080 "POST /process HTTP/1.1" 400 3023
<Response [400]>

>>> requests.post('http://localhost:8080/process', headers=headers, data='{}')
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:8080
send: b'POST /process HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\n\r\n'
send: b'{}'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Server: CherryPy/18.6.1
header: Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2022 23:17:00 GMT
header: Content-Length: 14
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:8080 "POST /process HTTP/1.1" 200 14
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

And you're correct with:

```
@cherrypy.tools.json_in(content_type=['application/json', 'text/plain'])
```

That is also required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which certainly fix my question. I have further follow up question. Now if the post handler uses `data='{"num1": [1,2,3], "num2": [4,5,6]}')` 
it still works. 
But if the post handler became `data=str({"num1": [1,2,3], "num2": [4,5,6]}))` it doesn't work. Any good idea?

Comment: The string representation of a python dictionary is not a valid JSON, you have to use the json module to encode it (json.dumps) if you really want to pass the information like that instead of using the json param that requests already provides.

Comment: using `json.dumps(...)` works! Thank you!